# SQL Server full outer group not getting all values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to full join two tables by their date with one table having columns call 'date', 'parties', 'total', etc and another table just having dates.

Below is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
    rangeDates.[ListOFDates], 
    partiesDetails.[Party], partiesDetails.[Amount] 
FROM rangeDates
       FULL OUTER JOIN partiesDetails
        ON rangeDates.[ListOFDates] = partiesDetails.[Date]
```

Now is the table `rangeDates` I have. Also there's a date for everyday for a set period of dates, for exmaple, below it starts at `'2017-02-02'` and may have a date everyday till `'2018-03-01'`

```
Ref      ListOFDates
1        2017-02-02
2        2017-02-03
3        2017-02-04
.........
```

And in the `partiesDetails` table

```
Date          Party      Amount
2017-02-03     Tuf        5000 
2017-04-01     Tuf        2000
2017-05-22     Wing       3000
.................
```

The ideal results I would want is:

```
ListOfDates   Party     Amount
2017-02-02     NULL      NULL
2017-02-03     Tuf       5000
2017-02-04     NULL      NULL
............
```

Comment: Your query should do this.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple outer join suffice?

Comment: Your query should already do this, although it shouldn't need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would appear to suit your requirements.  What do you get?  You told us what you wanted, provided sample data, and your query - great!  The only thing missing is what you are currently getting (that you don't want).

Answer (score 1):

I feel that maybe you should be using a calendar table here:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT CAST('20170202' AS date) AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '2018-03-01'
)

SELECT
    d.date,
    p.[Party],
    p.[Amount]
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN partiesDetails p
    ON d.date = p.[Date]
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

I make this suggestion because you used the language `and may have a date everyday till`, which seems to imply that maybe the `rangeDates` table does not in fact cover the entire date range you have in mind.